# Finding unbiased estimator of function of p from a geometric distribution

Tags: self-study, estimation, geometric-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be a random sample from the geometric distribution with $Pr(X_i=j)=p(1-p)^{j-1}$ for $i = 1, 2$, $j = 1, 2, \ldots$ and $0<p<1$.

Which statistics $T(X)$ could be an unbiased estimator for $\frac{p}{(1+p)}$?

My attempt: Let $T(X)$ be the required unbiased estimator. 
Then, $E(T(X))=\frac{p}{(1+p)}$ and
$$
\sum T(j)p(1-p)^{j-1}=p(1+p)^{-1}=p(1-p+p^{2}-p^{3}+...)
\\
\sum T(j)(1-p)^{j-1}=(1-p+p^{2}-p^{3}+...)
$$

Can we find the estimator by comparing the two sides of above equation? 
If not, how can we find the required unbiased estimator?

As it is said that $X$ is a random sample of size $2$, should we consider the joint pmf while finding the unbiased estimator?

Comment: That summation should be actually $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} T(j)(1-p)^{j-1}$ instead of $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} T(X)(1-p)^{j-1}$.

Comment: Recall the definition of expected value (to correct your formulas) and use $q=1-p$.

Comment: Since the pgf of this geometric pmf is $E(s^X)=\frac{ps}{1-(1-p)s}$, setting $\frac{ps}{1-(1-p)s}=\frac{p}{1+p}$ gives $s=\frac{1}{2}$. Hence an unbiased estimator based on two observations is simply $\frac{2^{-X_1}+2^{-X_2}}{2}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom , you should transform your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As is shown [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410948/119261) in a similar question, one can simply work with the PGF or MGF to find an unbiased estimator based on a single observation.

For a geometric variable $X$ with given pmf, we have

\begin{align}
E\left[t^X\right]&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty t^jp(1-p)^{j-1}
\\&=pt\sum_{j=1}^\infty ((1-p)t)^{j-1}
\\&=\frac{pt}{1-(1-p)t}\qquad\quad,\,\,\small|t|<\frac1{1-p}
\end{align}

Solving $\frac{pt}{1-(1-p)t}=\frac{p}{1+p}$ for $t$ gives $t=\frac12$.

That is, for every $p\in(0,1)$,

$$E\left[2^{-X}\right]=\frac{p}{1+p}$$

So an unbiased estimator of $\frac{p}{1+p}$ based on two observations $X_1$ and $X_2$ is simply $$T(X_1,X_2)=\frac{2^{-X_1}+2^{-X_2}}2$$